# How do I wrap a Matlab library without polluting my path variable?

Tags: matlab

Let us assume, I want to use a foreign Matlab library with a structure like this:

```
folderName
  play.m
  run.m
  open.m
```

If I simply add `folderName` to my Matlab path variable, it will easily yield name conflicts. I don't want to rename the files, to be able to obtain new releases of the example library (the package concept is not used in the example library). Renaming would need to modify the code as well, if there are calls from one library function to the other.

How do I write local wrappers, which wrap the functions from that example library? My wrappers could then have my desired names and input parameters.

Clarification: How do I use an external library (toolbox) without name conflicts, without renaming and without modifying each function?

- Rename files: Makes it hard to update the external library.
- Simply put them in a package folder: This will break internal library function calls.

Comment: Is the library just one folder (maybe with a private folder) or does it contain multiple source folders?

Comment: Let us assume, the library contains several folders.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a package, which will establish a namespace, such that things in the package, are then qualified with the package name.  You can find more information here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html

Comment: Could you explain how to do this without modifying the library? Every reference to other functions of the library must include the package name if you put it into a package.

Comment: I think @Daniel is right. This would cause us to modify each call of a library function to other library functions by adding a prefix.